# Вывести на экран несколько максимальных/минимальных элементов списка с привязкой к индексу

Tags: python, циклы, list, index

Пользователь вводит числа отдельными действиями, вывести на экран 2 максимальных значения(и порядковый номер). нужно использовать циклы и списки

```
a = float(input(''))
b = float(input(''))
c = float(input(''))
d = float(input(''))
e = float(input(''))
f = float(input(''))
A = [a, b, c, e, d, f]

l = list(enumerate(A))
l.sort(key=lambda i: i[0])
    

print( sorted(l)[0], sorted(l)[1])
print( sorted(l)[-1], sorted(l)[-2])
```

Comment: что не так в вашем коде?

Comment: Сортировка не нужна в `l.sort(key=lambda i: i[0])`.У вас там и так будут элементы в порядке увеличения индекса

Comment: Думаю так будет: `l = list(enumerate(A))` + `items = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[1])` + `print(items[0], items[-1])`

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
lambda i: i[0]
```

Надо писать

```
lambda i: i[1]
```

Ваш код можно уменьшить

```
arr = [(i, int(input())) for i in range(6)]

arr.sort(key = lambda el:el[1])

print(arr[0], arr[1])
print(arr[-1], arr[-2])
```